# Typescript interface set type of property from another property from the same interface

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have an interface containing two properties, and I want that the second property type to be equal to the first property, the first property type being a string for example.

```js
interface Argument {
  type: any;
  allowedValues: [insert way to infer type from `type` property]
}

const a: Argument = {
  type: 'string',
  allowedValues: 'test', // only because `type` property is a string
}
```

`type` property can be anything but allowedValues should be the same type as `type` (or an array of it)

Comment: The problem with this is that literally anything fits; whatever the value of `type`, it has type `any`, so `allowedValues` can have the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific concrete type in TypeScript corresponding exactly to what you consider a valid `argument`, where the `allowedValues` property must have the same type as the `type` property.  If you want to be able to represent this at all in TypeScript, you'll probably need to think of it as more of a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints), and use a helper function instead of a type annotation to validate that any given candidate value conforms to the constraint:

```
    interface Argument<T> {
      type: T;
      allowedValues: T
    }
    const asArgument = <T,>(a: Argument<T>) => a;
```

Here we are making a generic type `Argument<T>` that keeps track of the type of the `type` and `allowedValues` properties being correlated.  You can test it out:

```
const a = asArgument({
  type: 'string',
  allowedValues: 'test', // okay
});

asArgument({
  type: 123,
  allowedValues: 456
}); // okay

asArgument({
  type: 'string',
  allowedValues: 456 // error! Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
})
```

If you try to give `allowedValues` a value of a different type from that of `type`, you get an error.

---

Note that by making your `Argument` type generic, you'll need to drag around the extra generic type parameter `T` wherever you need to keep track of this constraint. I magine changing all mentions of `Argument` to `Argument<T>` and adding `T` to whatever scope is necessary. So I'd suggest only using this constraint for initial validation of developer-submitted arguments, and then widen it to a concrete type like `Argument<any>` for use in internal code that assumes it's already been validated.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJQOYFcC2FwA8AKgHzIDeAUMsmAJ4AOEAXMkQNzXJwA2PA9gHcIAEwBqvLBADOrIpQC+lBPxDSw3aemx5wyALzJiAGhIAKOK2258YYiQCUBsnE7LV67gc3XdYM1Q09EysAOTqUKAYocZcvALC4pIyYZDqMcgA9JnI-ADWcHSKDm6UcFqYNuABXMEsyACMAEwAzLE08UKiEjxSssgALACsAGzF7Fk5+YWUZRU6tjVBjPXhYJEg0e3cfF1JvSmDo5PI0FD8UACEbCvIoSC4AEbQocjA0sgg-Brl0sAYIDgjx4KDA-FotzWG2ixVmQA)

Comment: Great! But if I want an array of Arguments that can be any type, this type guard doesn't work.
```typescript
const b: Arguments<any>[] = [
  {
    type: 'test',
    allowedValues: 4 // no problem
  }
]
```